# Differences between md5pass and md5sum

Tags: command-line, bash, encryption, hash

This question may be insane ,but due to definition of hash algorithms, hash algorithms are some kind of functions that accept variable length input and make it encrypted and the output always has a fixed length and has same output by same input?
Consider the following results :

```
root@kali:~# echo "ENDER" | md5pass
$1$rdMOD9CB$LJtbTfwAM3aLuI8L2xOb5.
root@kali:~# echo "ENDER" | md5pass
$1$yINoNkna$Z26YKnZj2foWdTxSGfHOv0
root@kali:~#
root@kali:~#
root@kali:~# echo "ENDER" |md5sum
0ffe655d9777b70867a75c7562657317  -
root@kali:~# echo "ENDER" |md5sum
0ffe655d9777b70867a75c7562657317  -
```

As the cryptographic md5pass hashing program does change every output by the same input, So login systems such as Ubuntu login or etc how detect the correct password by any input ?

Finally, Could you give a well-explained but in short about such these hash functions ?
Or any thing else that could be useful to distinguish between the two ?
So thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First MD5 is a hash function that reads the whole file/string/input data and generates a defaultly 128-bit long hex-formatted hash. That hash is always the same when the file or the given string is the same.

With the utillity `md5pass` you do exactly the same, but the hash gets "salted". In cryptography, a "salt" is random data that is used as an additional input to a one-way function that hashes a password or passphrase to raise entropy. Thats why `md5pass` always outputs a different value.

**Why salting?**

The problem is that when users have the same password they have the same hash. If the hash gets salted randomly, every password has a different hash value. The salt must be saved separately in another table, because it is needed to vertify the password. In `md5pass` the salt can be defined (as the second argument). If no salt is defined the system geneates a random one.

Another advantage is that in case of MD5 or SHA [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) are less effective as without a salt, because,  without a salt, the hash value must be calculated just once for every password.